# Remove space between 2 words to be as one word in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have this code : v is variable consist from 2 words , i want to replace space and make them as one word at the last line name ="" . `

```
 $.each(val, function (i, v) {
        if($target.find('[name="select_'+type+'['+v+']"]').length) {

            $target.find('[name="select_'+type+'['+v+']"]').show().prop('disabled',false);
        }else{
            $target.append('<input from-select class="form-control" placeholder="'+v+'"  name="select_'+type+''+weekNo+''+v.replace(" ")+'">');
        }
    })

});
```

` doen't give an error but doesn't give what i want

Comment: can u add an example of the excepted result and actual result?

Comment: You need to tell it with what you want to replace it `"two words".replace(" ", "");`

Comment: v is Teacher activiy for example and i want it to be Teacheractivity means one word

Answer (score 1):

```
v.replace(" ", "")
```

That should work.